# Where does Google MyTracks store recorded files?

Tags: mytracks

I am not 100% sure of this but I seem to remember that in previous versions of MyTracks the recorded files were stored at **/mnt/sdcard/MyTracks**. But this does not seem to be the case any more. By previous I mean version prior to *at least* version **2.0.4** which is what I currently have.

I have recorded several tracks but can't find the files at **/mnt/sdcard/MyTracks**. In fact there is no such folder name on that location. So where does it store recorded files now? I need the GPX files.

I tried searching for "mytrack" and also "mytracks" (case insensitive) in File Expert app at **/mnt/sdcard** but it found no folders. It did find some files.

```
com.google.android.maps.mytracks
/mnt/sdcard/android/data/com.google.android.maps.mytracks

cache_vts_com.google.android.maps.mytracks.0
/mnt/sdcard/android/data/com.google.android.maps.mytracks/cache/
```

And additional 4 files in the same location. But I can't see any GPX files in here. Attempting to search at root causes File Expert process to crash.

Comment: @AlEverett Thanks! I was going to create a new tag by the name "google-mytracks" but my reputation score was not enough. So I had to use the generic "google" tag. Thanks for the edit! I have made a wiki for this new tag.

Answer (score 4):

I'm still not sure where actual MyTracks data is stored. I think it's stored somewhere in the internal memory, not in the external memory. But I have found a way to export the GPX data.

1. Start MyTracks.
2. Press Menu button.
3. Tap "Save all to external storage".
4. Tap "Save as GPX".

> Saved x tracks to /mnt/sdcard/MyTracks/gpx.

At least some of the data for Google MyTracks is stored at **/data/data/com.google.android.maps.mytracks**. But to view **/data/data** you need to enable the root explorer in the phone and you need root access.

To enable root explorer in File Expert:

1. Start File Expert.
2. Press Menu button.
3. Tap More.
4. Tap Settings.
5. Tap File Explorer Settings.
6. Check Root Explorer option.

For this to work you need root access on the phone, i.e. the phone needs to be rooted. Also, sometimes you will need to mount the file system as writable, and you can do this too within the app settings.

(I tried the same thing with ES File Explorer but I was unable to even view the root folder / with it, it was only able to view /sdcard. So therefore I recommend using File Explorer instead.)

Comment: Here's a Google Support article on the subject: https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/2391540?hl=en&ref_topic=2391064

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to check Google Drive because the app can store/sync to the "My Tracks" folder.

Answer (score 1):

I think track data is stored in **mytracks.db** rather than in any type of GPS file. This database is located at the below path. (root required to pull it out)

> /data/data/com.google.android.maps.mytracks/databases/mytracks.db (and
>   its -journal file)

You can view it by a SQLite tool such like SQLite Expert, and find detailed data of each track.

Recently, the touch panel of my mobile device was broken during recording. That's why I'm here...
In conclusion I have copied the database simply to the other device, and then all tracks were recovered including the unfinished track.

Steps:

1. Install MyTracks on the new device.
2. Pull **mytracks.db** and **mytracks.db-journal** from the old device.
3. Put **mytracks.db** and **mytracks.db-journal** into the new device,
   overwrite the original files.
4. Launch MyTracks on the new device. All tracks are recovered.

---

Finally, if you'd like to get GPX files, export them manually as [your own answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/48562/114108) mentioned. It might be the only way I know.

Comment: I think root requirement can be circumvented if you take `adb backup` of that app and extract it to retrieve the relevant `.db` file.

Answer (score 0):

On my Galaxy S4 running My Tacks 2.0.10 the pictures taken with the app end up in this directory in the camera's memory (not the SD Card):

```
MyTracks\pictures
```

There are subdirectories created for each track that I've taken pictures on. They are named `MyTracks123`, `MyTracks134`, etc.

The full path of the main directory appears to be:

```
/storage/emulated/0/MyTracks/pictures
```

These pictures are automatically synced to my other devices where I have My Tracks installed. This means I'll have to stop taking pictures on a track from within My Tracks. I also don't like that I can't tell My Tracks to put the pictures on the SD Card. Oh well, easy enough to just take the pictures outside of My Tracks.

I also do not see the pictures being synced up to the My Tracks directory on my Google Drive. Just the `.kmz` files seem to be synced there.